# Please explain step by step basic selenium configuration using json

Tags: java, json, selenium

I use selenium and i know how to configure testNG in it.
I have to perform automation testing on a website which fetches data using JSON.
in that website locating elements using id or css or xpath don't work.
I was told it uses json.

I want to see a sample code for using JSON in testNG format for any website for your choice.
I just want to see how to start and locate any one element. rest i can learn from that single sample code which you post.
The website for which i want to perform automation testing generates dynamic id's and xpath and css also consists of that id values. and locating elements by attributes is not working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do here is **web scraping**? Or Analyzing **web scraped data**?

Web scraping is one of the hottest topics around with integration to Big Data and analytics. However, it doesn't just use **CODE**. It's selenium automation that you need to go through, honestly.

I don't think anyone can teach you that in a single post here. You can try out some tutorials for the same at [UDEMY](http://www.udemy.com). 
Thank you.